# scipy csr_matrix: understand indptr

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Every once in a while, I get to manipulate a `csr_matrix` but I always forget how the parameters `indices` and `indptr` work together to build a sparse matrix.

I am looking for a clear and intuitive explanation on how the `indptr` interacts with both the `data` and `indices` parameters when defining a sparse matrix using the notation `csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)])`.

I can see from the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) that the `data` parameter contains all the non-zero data, and the `indices` parameter contains the columns associated to that data (as such, `indices` is equal to `col` in the example given in the documentation). But how can we explain in clear terms the `indptr` parameter?

Comment: It may help to look at the `lil` equivalent.  The successive slices `M.indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` as described by @Tanguy correspond to the lists in the `lil` `rows` array.

Comment: In words, `indptr` (index pointer) represents the indices for *partitioning* the `data` and `indices` (column indices). To fill in the matrix with the (nonzero) data, knowing the column indices is clearly not enough. The remaining info we need could be the row indices for each nonzero value, but another choice is to specify the way to partition the nonzero values (and at the same time the column indices), which is exactly csr formulation.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Maybe this explanation can help understand the concept:

- `data` is an array containing all the non zero elements of the sparse matrix.
- `indices` is an array mapping each element in `data` to its column in the sparse matrix.
- `indptr` then maps the elements of `data` and `indices` to the rows of the sparse matrix. This is done with the following reasoning:

  1. If the sparse matrix has **M** rows, `indptr` is an array containing **M+1** elements
  2. for row **i**, `[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` returns the indices of elements to take from `data` and `indices` corresponding to row **i**. So suppose `indptr[i]=k` and `indptr[i+1]=l`, the data corresponding to row **i** would be `data[k:l]` at columns `indices[k:l]`. This is the tricky part, and I hope the following example helps understanding it.

**EDIT** : I replaced the numbers in `data` by letters to avoid confusion in the following example.

[image]

Note: the values in `indptr` are necessarily increasing, because the next cell in `indptr` (the next row) is referring to the next values in `data` and `indices` corresponding to that row.

Comment: Thank you for trying to make it clear, but still not.. can you give an example of M and then do the point 2 from a row, explaining for what values in `indices` and `data` it comes? I tried to follow on an example and I didn't get it.

Comment: Thank you!  This post is helpful! It reminds me of my computational mathematics textbook, it has explained this. But why scipy does offer an official doc for the sparse matrix format in scipy.sparse?

Comment: Did you mean "why does scipy does **not** offer an official doc ..." ? :)

Comment: Took me a while to understand this (but much shorter than if I had to research it all my self), but I get it now. The part that tripped me up is the the consecutive values for data. Kept thinking the values represented the columns. If they were random values, I think it would help the reader come to an understanding faster. Great though. Thanks.

Comment: What if row 1 was all zeros? Do the values of indptr become 0,1,2,4,7? Or do indices and data receive  'null' values for their second positions? I'm thinking the former.

Comment: Should not the last element of `indptr` rather be 7 instead of 8?

Comment: @ivankeller: updating your question to the edited example / picture: "Should not the last element of indptr rather be 10 instead of 11?" --> no because the last element in a range is not selected when subsetting data structures in python (e.g.`data[l]` is not contained in `data[k:l]`).

Comment: @spacedustpi: I replaced the values in `data` by letters hoping it avoids further confusion. Regarding your question on empty rows, @a-nadjar gave an example. If the **i**-th row is empty, the **i**-th value of indptr is equal to the **i+1**-th value, so subsetting `data` and `indices` with the range `[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` does not return any value.

Comment: An image is worth a thousand words. Thank you!

Comment: @Tanguy, any chance you could make the svg (or other original file) of the image available? I'd be happy to use it to illustrate some scr_matrix algorithms I am using (and, of course, respect the CC BY-SA 4.0 license).

Comment: Amazing answer. Super helpful buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the elements inside indptr are in ascending order.
But how to explain the indptr behavior? In short words, until the element inside indptr is the same or doesn't increase, you can skip row index of the sparse matrix.

The following example illustrates the above interpretation of indptr elements:

Example 1) imagine this matrix:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7]])


mat1 = csr_matrix(([1,8,7], [1,0,2], [0,1,2,2,2,3]), shape=(5,3))
mat1.indptr
# array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
mat1.todense()  # to get the corresponding sparse matrix
```

Example 2) Array to CSR_matrix (the case when the sparse matrix already exists):

```
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                [8, 0, 0],
                [0, 5, 4],
                [0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 7]])


mat2 = csr_matrix(arr))
mat2.indptr
# array([0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
mat2.indices
# array([0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
mat.data
# array([8, 5, 4, 7], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example:

```
indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
array([[1, 0, 2],
      [0, 0, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]])
```

To read `indptr` do this-

- Ignore `indptr[0] = 0`
- `indptr[1] = 2` tells the number of non-zero data elements, upto end of first row
- `indptr[2] = 3` tells the number of non-zero data elements, starting from beggining upto end of second row.
- `indptr[3] = 6` tells the number of non-zero data elements, starting from beginning upto end of third row.

Answer (score 1):

```
indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
array([[1, 0, 2],
      [0, 0, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]])
```

In the above example from scipy documentation.

- The data array contains the non-zero elements present in the sparse matrix traversed row-wise.
- The indices array gives the column number for each non-zero data point.
- For example :-col[0] for the first element in data i.e. 1, col[2] for second element in data i.e. 2 and so on till the last data element, so the size of the data array and the indices array is same.
- The indptr array basically indicates the location of the first element of the row. Its size is one more than the number of rows.
- For example :- the first element of indptr is 0 indicating the first element of row[0] present at data[0] i.e. '1', the second element of indptr is 2 indicating the first element in row[1] which is present at data[2] i.e. the element '3' and the third element of indptr is 3 indicating that the first element of row[2] is at data[3] i.e. '4'.
- Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a sparse matrix, it means that the non-zero elements in the matrix are relatively very few compared to the whole elements($m \times n$).

We use :

- `data` to store all the non-zero elements out there, from left to right, top to bottom
- `indices` to store all the column indices for each of these data
- `indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]` to represent the slice in `data` field to find row[i]'s all non-zero elements

Answer (score 1):

**It's actually quite simple.**

`indptr` is a list showing for each column, one by one, at what element's index this column begins.

For example:

```py
rows = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
cols = np.array([0, 2, 0, 0, 1])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
sparse_matrix = csc_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))
[[1, 0, 2],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [4, 5, 0]]

indptr = sparse_matrix.indptr
[0, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here is the secret:

```py
col_data = sparse_matrix.data  # data, column-by-column
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

`indptr` is a list of indices in `col_data` where **each new column** begins.

See for yourself:

- column `0` starts with element **1** which is at index `0 = indptr[0]` in *col_data*
- column `1` starts with element **5** which is at index `3 = indptr[1]` in *col_data*
- column `2` starts with element **2** which is at index `4 = indptr[2]` in *col_data*
- column `3` would begin at index `5 = indptr[3]` in *col_data*, i.e. right outside of it

Answer (score 0):

Think of the values in indptr as the **number of non-zero elements already passed by** before the start of a specific row in the pre-compressed (sparse) format. This is a handful to understand but the example below should clarify.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

array_for_csr = np.array([[2, 0, 19, 5],
                          [8, 0, 0, 1],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [4, 6, 6, 0]])
matrix = csr_matrix(array_for_csr)
print(matrix)
"""
(0, 0)  2
(0, 2)  19
(0, 3)  5
(1, 0)  8
(1, 3)  1
(3, 0)  4
(3, 1)  6
(3, 2)  6
"""
print(matrix.indices)
# [0 2 3 0 3 0 1 2]
print(matrix.indptr)
# [0 3 5 5 8]
```

Ex.

indptr[0] = 0 since 0 values in the matrix have been passed by before
the start of the 1st row in the pre-compressed matrix (There are no values passed since we haven't started traversing the matrix)

indptr[1] = 3 since 3 values in the matrix have been passed by before the start of the 2nd row in the pre-compressed matrix (values 2, 19, 5)

indptr[2] = 5 since 5 values in the matrix have been passed by before the start of the 3rd row in the pre-compressed matrix (values 2, 19, 5, 8, 1)

indptr[3] = 5 since 5 values in the matrix have been passed by before the start of the 4th row in the pre-compressed matrix (since all values in 4rd row of pre-compressed matrix were zero)

indptr[4] = 8 since 8 values in the matrix have been past by before the start of the 5th row in the pre-compressed matrix (the last value in the indptr array will always be equal to the number of non-zero values in the pre-compressed (sparse) matrix