# Efficient Iteration Over Non-Zero Elements in Each Row of a Scipy Sparse CSR Matrix

Tags: python, performance, loops, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with a `scipy.sparse` matrix in CSR format and need to iterate over each row to retrieve the indices and values of non-zero elements.

I've read about methods to [iterate efficiently over a CSR matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/iterating-through-a-scipy-sparse-vector-or-matrix), but I haven't succeeded in modifying them to meet my requirements.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
#'matrix' is a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
for index in tqdm(range(matrix.shape[0]), desc="Updating values", leave=False):
    row = matrix.getrow(index)
    values_indices = row.indices
    # Further processing...
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: *"modifying them"* Do you only modify the values without changing the matrix structure (i.e. the position of the nnz values or their number)? *"meet my requirements"* I it certainly better to provide them so to better help you (for example knowing a bit more about what *"Further processing"* does with the variables.

Comment: You can iterate on the `indptr` of the CSR format.  This has been discussed in various SO.  One I found wirh a quick searxh is https://stackoverflow.com/q/52299420/901925

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get the content of each row without converting to COO and iterating over the values in the matrix, and doing so is generally faster, for three reasons.

1. First, converting CSR to COO is slower than doing nothing.
2. Second, in the COO loop, the loop must compare each row coordinate to check whether it has changed from the previous row coordinate, in order to recover where each row begins and ends. In contrast, the CSR format gives us this information for free.
3. Third, taking a slice from an array allows us to get an array representing the data without actually copying it.

The following function calls a function on each row's values and indices, looping over it by using indptr to find the beginning and end of each row.

```
def get_matrix_rows(matrix, func):
    rows = matrix.shape[0]
    for index in range(rows):
        indptr_start = matrix.indptr[index]
        indptr_end = matrix.indptr[index + 1]
        values = matrix.data[indptr_start:indptr_end]
        indices = matrix.indices[indptr_start:indptr_end]
        func(indices, values)
```

Note a difference in behavior: if the matrix has no elements on a row, this implementation calls the function with an empty indices and values array, whereas the other implementation skips rows without any nonzero values.

Here is a benchmark script that compares the two implementations. It makes the following assumptions:

1. The matrix is 10,000 by 5,000, starts in CSR format, and is composed of random values at a density of 1%.
2. The conversion into COO is counted as part of the COO method.
3. Each function must find the values and column indexes of each row and call the provided function.

Code:

```py
import scipy.sparse
matrix = scipy.sparse.random(10000, 5000, format='csr', density=0.01)


def donothing(*args):
    pass


def get_matrix_original(matrix, func):
    for index in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        row = matrix.getrow(index)
        indices = row.indices
        values = row.data
        func(indices, values)


def get_matrix_rows_coo(matrix, func):
    coo_matrix = matrix.tocoo()
    old_i = None
    indices = []
    values = []

    for i, j, v in zip(coo_matrix.row, coo_matrix.col, coo_matrix.data):
        if i != old_i:
            if old_i is not None:
                func(indices, values)
            indices = [j]
            values = [v]
        else:
            indices.append(j)
            values.append(v)
        old_i = i

    # Handle the last group
    if indices and values:
        func(indices, values)


def get_matrix_rows_njo(matrix, func):
    rows = matrix.shape[0]
    for index in range(rows):
        indptr_start = matrix.indptr[index]
        indptr_end = matrix.indptr[index + 1]
        values = matrix.data[indptr_start:indptr_end]
        indices = matrix.indices[indptr_start:indptr_end]
        func(indices, values)


%timeit get_matrix_original(matrix, donothing)
%timeit get_matrix_rows_coo(matrix, donothing)
%timeit get_matrix_rows_njo(matrix, donothing)
```

Benchmark results:

```
.getrow() method
634 ms ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
COO and iterate method
270 ms ± 4.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
CSR method
12.4 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note that at sufficiently low densities, (approx ~0.05% nonzero values) the COO method is faster than the CSR method, because the COO method does not need to do anything for empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a more efficient way to iterate over non-zero elements in each row of a scipy sparse CSR matrix compared to the method I initially used. Here's a summary of both methods and their performance:

Initial Method (Using getrow):

```
#  'csr_matrix' is a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
for user_index in range(csr_matrix.shape[0]):
    row = csr_matrix.getrow(user_index)
    values_indices = row.indices
```

this method took 2.9309 seconds for a matrix with 10,000 rows and 5,000 columns.

The second method which I based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319014/iterating-through-a-scipy-sparse-vector-or-matrix):

```
start_time = time.time()
    old_i = None
    indices = []
    values = []
    
    for i, j, v in zip(coo_matrix.row, coo_matrix.col, coo_matrix.data):
        if i != old_i:
            if old_i is not None:
                other_method(indices, values)
            indices = [j]
            values = [v]
        else:
            indices.append(j)
            values.append(v)
        old_i = i
    
    # Handle the last group
    if indices and values:
        other_method(indices, values)
    
    end_time = time.time()
```

This method took only 0.0030 seconds for the same matrix size.

However, I'm not sure both of them are best practices.

Comment: `getrow` returns a (1,n) csr matrix, which reduces the speed.  Using  the `indptr` to get a slice of `indices` is more direct.  The `lil` format stores row indices/values as lists in object dtype arrays, and has a `getrow` that returns a more efficient  `view`.